# How to import SQL database using raw /var/lib/mysql file structure?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-12.04, database-backups

I need to restore a database on a fresh install, unfortunately I wasn't able to perform a proper `.sql` backup of my previous db, I was only able to access the filesystem so I tarballed the entire `/var/lib/mysql` directory.

Inside that mysql folder I see a folder with the name of the db I want to restore, but simply copying that file into `/var/lib/mysql/` on my new server doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this may help

1) shutdown new instance

2) del the Stuff you copied there

3) Start instance again

4) create Database Command

5) shut it down again

6) copy your files

7) restart mysql

**you Must use the Same version number as before**

Comment: When you say shut down/start new instance, do you mean I run `sudo service mysql stop/start`? Also what does Step 4 relate to?

Comment: @james yes, i meant starting/stopping the instance with sudo mysql ...
the "create" command is meant to be executed in mysql-shell, it should create all relevant table-entries in the mysql-database and also the directories in /var/lib
i mentioned the "start/stop" things so that mysql doesnt get confused about the new files( filehandles )